# Vaadin refuses to align image in a HorizontalLayout

Tags: image, vaadin8

I'm using `Vaadin 8` and I have a HorizontalLayout at the very top of the page.  It's in a VeritcalLayout which is the main content of the UI.

Something like:

```
UI
    VerticalLayout (margin=false, spacing=false)
        HorizontalLayout (margin=false, spacing=false)
```

So you would expect everything to align to the edges of the browser viewport.  I also have set default component alignment on everything to `TOP LEFT`.

Now, I want to put an image in the upper-right of that HorizontalLayout.  The image aligns to the right of the screen as expected but the top of the image has about 30-40 pixels of padding that I cannot get rid of.

Imagine the black box as the logo I am using:

[image]

My UI init:

```
@SpringUI
@Theme("valo")
@PushStateNavigation
public class CustomUI extends UI implements ViewDisplay {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3026091945679596519L;

    @Autowired
    private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @Autowired
    private SpringNavigator navigator;


    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        setSizeFull();

        final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
        root.setMargin(false);
        root.setSpacing(false);
        root.setSizeFull();
        setContent(root);

        navigator.init(this, root);
    }

    @Override
    public void showView(View view) {
        this.setContent((Component) view);
    }
```

My HorizontalLayout:

```
    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(false);
    layout.setSpacing(false);
    layout.setHeight(64, Unit.PIXELS);
    layout.setWidth("100%");

    String basePath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    FileResource logo = new FileResource(new File(basePath + "/WEB-INF/images/logo.PNG"));

    Image logoImg = new Image("", logo);

    layout.addComponent(logoImg);
    layout.setComponentAlignment(logoImg, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
```

The image is 64 pixels tall.  The HorizontalLayout is also 64 pixels tall according to the debugger.
But notice how far off it is on the top.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
Image logoImg = new Image("", logo);
```

into

```
Image logoImg = new Image(null, logo);
```

Components in a HorizontalLayout have their caption on top of the component. If the caption is not null, i.e. it is empty it does take the aforementioned 30-40 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like it looks like that UI itself still has margin. So you need to disable in.

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    setSizeFull();
    setMargin(false); // this was missing

    final VerticalLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
    root.setMargin(false);
    root.setSpacing(false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give enough detail.  My UI extends UI and implements ViewDisplay so there is no setMargin.  I will update my question.